# Access to the dex task is now impossible, how to upgrade to 1.5.0?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dex

I want to upgrade gradle to 2.0.0-beta or 1.5.0, I have the dex plugin in my gradle at the moment, but even when I removed it I was still getting the same error. How do I properly get rid of the multidex dependency

```
Error:Access to the dex task is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0
1.4.0 introduces a new Transform API allowing manipulation of the .class files.
See more information: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api
```

build.gradle [More info on multidex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

The Transform API doesn't give too much info. 
Is there any to get this work or any examples how to use the transform api, anything at all?

I know it works with 1.3.0, I need at least 1.5.0

Comment: What is "the dex plugin"?  Perhaps you should show your entire build.gradle.

Comment: Remove `com.android.support:multidex` from dependencies. It's part of the Gradle build since Gradle 1.4.0.

Comment: @StenSoft my gradle version is 1.3.0, that's my problem I can't upgrade to any version above that, tried removing the multidex code entirely.

Answer (score 1):

At the project level `build.gradle`, put this (or whatever version you need)

```
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
 }
```

As far as

> How do I properly get rid of the multidex dependency?

You need to remove all references to multidex in the Gradle files, then sync Gradle and clean and rebuild the project

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's going to help. I got a similar error and I deleted the directory which contained that dex file. The path was C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\AppName\app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\37393618208634. After deleting that directory it worked. You can try this if that does't work you can just put it back. I hope this helps.